Why there is permission denied error in App Specific folders on external storage from Android API 33?
I am trying to create few files in Android app-specific folder in external storage. As this is specific to my app only and not required for the user purpose so, its placed at this location.
The API that I am using is getExternalFilesDir. If I try to create the folder using mkdir at this location, it is giving me return value as -1 and errno with the value of PERMISSION_DENIED. As this API doesn't require any permission from the user, we should be able to create files and directory at this place.
This is observed from only Android's API 33 version. Is there anything changed?
Edit:
// This is the Main activity class
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var externalAppSpecificPath : String

    public external fun CreateDir (pString: String)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Example of a call to a native method
        binding.sampleText.text = stringFromJNI()

        externalAppSpecificPath = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir("").toString()
        Log.d ("TAG", externalAppSpecificPath)


        // Jumping to C++
        CreateDir (externalAppSpecificPath)

    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'testapp' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    external fun stringFromJNI(): String

    companion object {
        // Used to load the 'testapp' library on application startup.
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("testapp")
        }
    }
}

// CPP file 

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_testapp_MainActivity_CreateDir(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring p_string) {


    const char * string  = env->GetStringUTFChars(p_string, nullptr);
    const char * subfolder = "/subfolder";


    int newlength = strlen(string) + strlen(subfolder) + 1;

    char * newstring = new char [newlength];
    strcpy(newstring, string);
    strcat(newstring, subfolder);

    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "Tag", "New string->%s", newstring);

    int ret_val = mkdir ((const char *) newstring, S_IRWXU);


    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "Tag", "mkdir return value-->%d, errno-->%d", ret_val, errno);
}



Please show a [mre]

Can you share a code sample?

Added a minimal reproducible example

Only call mkdir if the directory does not exist yet. If it already exists mkdir will return false.

return value as -1 mkdir returns true or false. What would -1 be? You did not tell.

@blackapps If the response is -1, usually seems that your path is not writable.
